# Get subscriptions from AWS SNS using java

Tags: amazon-sns, aws-java-sdk, aws-java-sdk-2.x

How to get the list of subscriptions from AWS SNS belongs to particular topic using java code? Is it possible to get it?

If possible kindly some one suggest how to achieve this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [listSubscriptionsByTopic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sns/AmazonSNSClient.html#listSubscriptionsByTopic-com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.ListSubscriptionsByTopicRequest-) method.